# Heroku Node.js Error heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"

Tags: node.js, git, express, heroku

I'm trying to get my CRUD Node application deployed to Heroku and unable to send the index page to even get started. I've commented out everything in the application that deals with the API and just want to serve an index page but for some reason unable to do so.

Note, I'm not using nor want to use any type of rendering engine like EJS if all possible for right now.

**Directory Structure:**

```
/invoicr (root)
  package.json
  Procfile
  server.js
  /client
    index.html
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "invoicr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.7"
  }
}
```

**Procfile** (Not sure if I need this as package.json has the scripts start command)

```
web: node server.js
```

**server.js**

```
var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));    
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('/index.html'); //I've tried playing around with the path multiple ways and still get errors
});

app.listen(port);
```

I was able to get a simple response to work with:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
  res.end('<h1>World</h1>');
}); 
server.listen(port);
```

But as soon as I comment that out `var server = ...` and try to serve an html file I get the following error:
`heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=invoicr-test-app.herokuapp.com`

**Deployment Commands**

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "message"`
- `git push heroku master`
- `heroku ps:scale web=1`
- `heroku open`

Any help on what I'm missing or not doing correctly would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**Edit**

So as always it's something simple, looks like my dependencies weren't installing because I had them set as dev in the `package.json`. Thanks to everyone for helping me troubleshoot this issue.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "invoicr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.4.7"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');`?

Comment: Try that `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'client/') });`

Comment: So before I can do the following suggestions looks like Express will not install in Heroku. `Error: Cannon find module 'express'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default heroku doesn't install deps at `devDependencies` you need to set as `dependencies`

From Heroku:

> Npm reads configuration from any environment variables beginning with
>   NPM_CONFIG. We set production=true by default to install dependencies
>   only. If you would like to install additional devDependencies, you can
>   disable this behavior:  heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

Comment: Just discovered that, I was looking at other source code, realized the devDepenencies, dropped the dev, and literally just got the thing to deploy :).